What kinds of non-contact probes are useful in troubleshooting RF in amateur radio receiver and transmatch (antenna tuner) circuits?
I am an amateur radio hobbyist, learning to troubleshoot and repair old devices like radio receivers, and have found modern inexpensive digital storage oscilloscopes very handy for direct measurement of RF (from 2 to 25 mhz), and I understand why directly connecting a probe and its ground is important when using a scope.     Given that you would not be connecting either end, in a non-contact scope, I’ve been interested to see use cases for audio and RF signal troubleshooting (finding where in a circuit the signal goes away completely or becomes massively attenuated or destroyed) without direct contact to a dozen or a hundred places in a circuit.
What standard type non-contact probe would be most useful for detecting very very small audio or RF signals, such as those in a vintage (1970s or older) radio receiver, and are such non-contact problems usually home-brewed or are there commercial ones commonly used by people who work on radios?  Ones that would let you get close to a signal and “see it” without any DC contact?

So far the only thing I've found online to help me figure the answer to the above out is that various custom designs for non-contact probes tend to be shared among hobbyist and professional communications/radio repair techs communities.
Example: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uVkJqqZroN0
